# connection.on is not a function in mongoose v4.13

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to clear collection of the entire database but what's wrong with below code?

const mongoose = require('mongoose')
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise

const connection = mongoose.connect(
  `mongodb://admin@example.com/myDB`
)

```
exports.default = (dropAllCollections = () => {
  connection.on('open', function() {
    connection.db.listCollections().toArray(function(err, names) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err)
      } else {
        console.log(names)
      }

      mongoose.connection.close()
    })
  })
})()
```

How to find if something has changed in mongoose api? above code is from one of the answer in other question.

Answer (score 0):

Still you are using old version of mongoose, you can try using **`connection.db.collectionNames`**

Try running your collection names function after connection.

```
connection.on('open', function (ref) {
    connection.db.collectionNames(function (err, names) {
        console.log(names);      
    });
})
```

you can read the docs from **[here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/4.x/)** and **[`here`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/meta/changes-from-1.0/)**

Comment: The error is here `  connection.on('open', function(ref) {
             ^

TypeError: connection.on is not a function
`

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry about ressurrecting this topic, but if anyone has the same problem (I'm using 4.13 too), go to your tsconfig.json and delete the following line:

```
"esModuleInterop": true
```